# Bound mismatch: The type Node is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparator<T>> of the type MaxHeap<T>

Tags: java

```
public class MaxHeap<T extends Comparator<T>> { 
    private T[] Heap;
}
public class Node<T> implements Comparator<Node>{
}
public class Main {
    private static MaxHeap<Node> heap;
}
```

I get an error:

> Bound mismatch: The type `Node` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Comparator<T>>` of the type `MaxHeap<T>`

when i try to define this. All of them are different classes. I don't know why, i'm new using generic class, then i'm not sure what im doing bad, if i get out generic class from node, i mean like that:

```
public class Node implements Comparator<Node>{
}
```

it works fine.

Comment: `Node<T> implements Comparator<Node<T>>` --- You were missing a `<T>` there at the end. --- And you need `MaxHeap<Node<String>>` or whatever type you use that is a `Comparable`

Comment: Ask yourself: what kind of Node do you want in your heap, a Node<String>, a Node<Integer>? You have to choose something. Same thing for the node itself: what should Node<T> be comparable against? Against Node? That does not make much sense. Against Node<String>? Might be right in some cases... Against Node<T> - yes.

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea to have raw types here `MaxHeap<Node>` or anywhere else. Add whatever you're comparing to it to make it `MapHeap<Node<SomeType>>` instead. Without that, your object will be harder to use safely.

Comment: Okey , thank you all, i tried something like `public class MaxHeap<Node extends Comparator<Node>> { ` and now it doens't give me error, i also put on main like `MaxHeap<Node<SomeType>>`;

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `Comparable` instead of `Comparator`?